# Using ElasticSearch can I filter out results based on the relevance?

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

From the query, can I say something like, leave out results that have a relevance score less than 0.01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add a [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html) to your query like this:

```
{
  "min_score": 0.1,
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to do the same inside a query or filter (to use in aggregations then, or combine with other queries/filters) - i.e. without a top level request body search parameter?